# Matrices help - index 3 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 3 BUT I'm pretty sure I have a (3,n) matrix

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matrix, rotational-matrices

I keep getting error 'index 3 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 3' but I'm sure that I'm using a (3,n) matrix rather than a (n,3) one. I'm not very familiar with matrices in python so have been using a kind of hacky way of getting them into the shape I want so I can multiply or add them. Can anyone see where I've gone wrong or suggest some better practice?

I'm trying to perform a rotational transform on A, generated via:

```
A = array(random.rand(3, 9));
```

where A is containes a set of x,y,z coordinates in every column. E.g:

```
   Matrix A:
 [[0.70799333 0.77123425 0.07271538 0.52498025 0.84353825 0.78331767
  0.06428417 0.25629863 0.6654734  0.77562903]
 [0.34179928 0.83233168 0.3920859  0.19819796 0.22486337 0.09274312
  0.49057914 0.69716143 0.613912   0.04940198]
 [0.98522559 0.71273242 0.70784866 0.61589377 0.34007973 0.34492078
  0.44491238 0.37423906 0.37427018 0.13558728]]
```

The translated matrix is calculated via A_translated = re_R.(each column of A) + ret_t, where

```
 ret_R:  
[[ 0.1928724   0.90776212  0.372516  ]
 [ 0.27931303 -0.41473028  0.8660156 ]
 [ 0.94062983 -0.06298194 -0.33353981]]
```

and

```
  ret_t:
[[0.93445859]
 [0.59949888]
 [0.77385835]]
```

My attempt was as follows

```
count = 0
num_rows, num_cols = A.shape
translated_A = pd.DataFrame( zeros( (num_rows, num_cols) ) )
print('Translated A: \n', translated_A)

for i in range(0, num_cols): 

    multiply = ret_R.A[:,i] # works up until (not including) i = 3
    #IndexError: index 3 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 3
    print('Multiply: \n', multiply)
    multiply2 = np.matrix(pd.DataFrame(multiply))
    matrix = multiply2 + ret_t #works
    matrix2 = pd.DataFrame(matrix) #np.matrix(pd.DataFrame(matrix)) # not working ?
    print('Matrix:', matrix2)
    translated_A[i] = matrix2[0]
    
print(translated_A)
```

The line multiply = ret_R.A[:,i] only works up until and not including i = 3, which suggests that my A matrix is n,3 but I'm sure it's 3,n. I kept switching between matrices and data frames as this seemed to work but it doesn't work past i = 2.

Answer (score 0):

I've realised that I should be using an '@' to find the dot product of the matrices properly rather than a '.' and I had to transpose multiply2 to get an matrix in the form [ [] [] [] ]. I no longer have to keep switching between a data frame and matrix